todo.js:250 Error marking todo: SendTransactionError: Simulation failed
todo.js:250 Error marking todo: SendTransactionError: Simulation failed. Error marking todo: SendTransactionError: Simulation failed. 
Message: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 2: custom program error: 0x1773. 
Logs: 
[
  "Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success",
  "Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]",
  "Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success",
  "Program Z2DbEnaeMcFaiaMa43ikadWefUAfCdjjyV5QgoWdQyu invoke [1]",
  "Program log: Instruction: MarkTodo",
  "Program log: Marking todo with index: 0",
  "Program log: Todo marked status before: true",
  "Program log: AnchorError thrown in 93aa751f-44d8-495b-97ab-93acfd6604df/src/lib.rs:51. Error Code: AlreadyMarked. Error Number: 6003. Error Message: Already marked.",
  "Program Z2DbEnaeMcFaiaMa43ikadWefUAfCdjjyV5QgoWdQyu consumed 9121 of 199700 compute units",
  "Program Z2DbEnaeMcFaiaMa43ikadWefUAfCdjjyV5QgoWdQyu failed: custom program error: 0x1773"
]. 
Catch the `SendTransactionError` and call `getLogs()` on it for full details.
    at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (index.browser.esm.js:7525:13)
    at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (index.browser.esm.js:7490:20)
    at async sendAndConfirmRawTransaction (index.js:1122:23)
    at async AnchorProvider.sendAndConfirm (index.js:1012:20)
    at async markTodo (todo.js:243:31)`

lib.rs
pub fn mark_todo(ctx: Context<MarkTodo>, _todo_idx: u8) -> Result<()> {
        let todo_account = &mut ctx.accounts.todo_account;

        // Log the current status of the TODO for debugging
        msg!("Marking todo with index: {}", _todo_idx);
        msg!("Todo marked status before: {}", todo_account.marked);

        // Check if the TODO is already marked
        require!(!todo_account.marked, TodoError::AlreadyMarked);

        // Mark the todo
        todo_account.marked = true;

        // Log the status after marking
        msg!("Todo marked successfully.");
        msg!("Todo marked status after: {}", todo_account.marked);

        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn remove_todo(ctx: Context<RemoveTodo>, _todo_idx: u8) -> Result<()> {
        // Fetch the user profile account
        let user_profile = &mut ctx.accounts.user_profile;

        // Ensure there are todos to remove
        require!(user_profile.todo_count > 0, TodoError::NoTodos);

        // Safely decrease total todo count
        user_profile.todo_count = user_profile.todo_count.checked_sub(1).unwrap();

        // Log removal action for debugging purposes
        msg!(
            "Todo with index {} removed successfully. New todo count: {}",
            _todo_idx,
            user_profile.todo_count
        );

        // PDA for the todo_account is closed automatically in the context, no explicit closure needed

        Ok(())
    }
    ```


This is a custom error from your program where you have already marked the task as true.
The require! macro ascertains that a particular condition is true of the left side else it errors out with the specified error on the right.
!todo_account.marked must be returning false, causing the error.
require!(!todo_account.marked, TodoError::AlreadyMarked);

docs: https://docs.rs/anchor-lang/latest/anchor_lang/macro.require.html#:~:text=Macro%20anchor_lang%3A%3Arequire&text=Ensures%20a%20condition%20is%20true,without%20a%20custom%20error%20type.
